# css hover to change non-hovering div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class='checked' id='rb01'></div>
<div class='rb' id='rb02'></div>
<div class='rb' id='rb03'></div>
<div class='rb' id='rb04'></div>
```

css

```
.rb{
    display:inline-block;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:0 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rb:hover {
    background-color:#B30000;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
}
.checked{
    display:inline-block;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:0 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#B30000;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

So hovering a `.rb` div it becomes red and it works.
But, how can I make that, when hovering a `.rb` div, any div which is `.checked` - becomes non-red, i.e. - `.rb` ?

Comment: javascript / jquery? or some super-cool features of ccs3 i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery, you may try something like;

```
$( ".rb" ).mouseover(function() {
    $(".checked").css('background-color', 'blue');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(".checked").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yBNeq/)** is a working demo.

Answer (score 2):

As the `.rb` and the `.checked` containers are not nested nor related, what you are looking for is probably some `javascript` solution.

[jQuery provides a .hover() method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) that you can use to achieve your goal with just a few lines (say, on hover for .rb element you can add an extra CSS class for the .checked div, and provided you define non-red styles for this `.checked.new-class` in your css, you'll have it made :)

Answer (score 0):

you can give css like this

```
.rb:not(.checked):hover { do css here}
```

Comment: The `.rb` div is never `.checked`.